# CKeditor Recording Problem Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I cannot record CKeditor actions in Selenium IDE. I have added the following commands in my test case, but my problem is that on my page I have a button to save/send some data (from ckeditor too) and when Selenium clicks on the Save button, the written data in ckeditor disappears.

```
focus  |  class=cke_show_borders
typeKeys |  class=cke_show_borders  | testing content
runScript | CKEDITOR.instances["editor1"].setData('testContent');
```

Any help?

Comment: What is CKeditor?

Comment: Why are you using Selenium IDE rather than Selenium Builder?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add delay after `SetData` method, so the code will look like:

```
focus  |  class=cke_show_borders
typeKeys |  class=cke_show_borders  | testing content
runScript | CKEDITOR.instances["editor1"].setData('testContent');
pause 2000;
```

And then press 'Save' button.